# How can I troubleshoot a deadlock in mysql driver code?

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, deadlock, apache-commons-dbcp

If I throw enough traffic at a performance environment, I can cause out of memory errors.  If I do a thread dump on this instance, it will report a deadlock:

```
Found one Java-level deadlock:
=============================
"http-nio-8080-exec-9":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x00007fb528003098 (object 0x00000000826d6018, a com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancedConnectionProxy),
  which is held by "Finalizer"
"Finalizer":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x00007fb528002fe8 (object 0x00000000826d5f98, a com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationConnectionProxy),
  which is held by "http-nio-8080-exec-9"
```

I think the OOM is happening because the Finalizer is deadlocked and can't garbage collect unused instances.  I'm not sure how to troubleshoot the deadlock though.  The http-nio-8080-exec-9 thread is doing this:

```
"http-nio-8080-exec-9":
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MultiHostConnectionProxy$JdbcInterfaceProxy.invoke(MultiHostConnectionProxy.java:104)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000000826d6018> (a com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancedConnectionProxy)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.setPingTarget(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationConnectionProxy.invokeMore(ReplicationConnectionProxy.java:311)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MultiHostConnectionProxy.invoke(MultiHostConnectionProxy.java:457)
    - locked <0x00000000826d5f98> (a com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationConnectionProxy)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:291)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:291)
   my code here
```

On this line of my code, my code is doing this:

```
preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
```

The finalizer thread is doing this:

```
"Finalizer":
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.realClose(ResultSetImpl.java:6597)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000000826d5f98> (a com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationConnectionProxy)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.close(ResultSetImpl.java:851)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor112.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MultiHostConnectionProxy$JdbcInterfaceProxy.invoke(MultiHostConnectionProxy.java:108)
    - locked <0x00000000826d6018> (a com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancedConnectionProxy)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.close(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor112.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MultiHostConnectionProxy$JdbcInterfaceProxy.invoke(MultiHostConnectionProxy.java:108)
    - locked <0x00000000826d6018> (a com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancedConnectionProxy)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.close(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.close(DelegatingResultSet.java:169)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.close(DelegatingStatement.java:149)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.finalize(DelegatingStatement.java:549)
    at java.lang.System$2.invokeFinalize(System.java:1270)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Finalizer.java:98)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Finalizer.java:34)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:210)
```

The `ResultSetImpl.realClose` is doing this when it deadlocks:

```
synchronized (locallyScopedConn.getConnectionMutex()) {
```

Both seem related to mysql jdbc drivers.  We are using `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource` for our connection pooling.  Here's the code where we set up our connection:

```
private static final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

private void setUpConnectionPool()
{
    final String JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING = System.getProperty("JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING");
    final String DB_USER_STRING = System.getProperty("DB_USER_STRING");
    final String DB_PASSWORD_STRING = System.getProperty("DB_PASSWORD_STRING");
    final int MAX_CONNECTIONS = System.getProperty("MAX_CONNECTIONS") == null  ? 100 : Integer.valueOf(System.getProperty("MAX_CONNECTIONS"));

    try {

        ReplicationDriver driver = new ReplicationDriver();
        dataSource.setUrl(JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING);
        dataSource.setDriver(driver);
        dataSource.setUsername(DB_USER_STRING);
        dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD_STRING);
        dataSource.setMaxTotal(MAX_CONNECTIONS);
        dataSource.setConnectionProperties("autoReconnect=true;roundRobinLoadBalance=true;");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The above method is called when the context is initialized.  Then, all code gets its connection by calling this method:

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return dataSource.getConnection();
}
```

I'm hoping there's something obviously wrong with this code, but I don't see an obvious reason why it would cause a deadlock.

Comment: Looks like the finalizer is closing a `Statement` object. Why is that? Seems your code is not managing your resources correctly. You should always close a `Statement` in a `finally` block when you're done with it. Better yet, use try-with-resources. If you write good code, this problem wouldn't happen. Fix the cause, not the symptom.

Comment: @Andreas thank you for that insight!  I'll look into it.

Comment: @Andreas is there an easier way to discover the code causing the problem than scouring the whole code base?

Comment: If you're not closing resources properly, then either you're doing JDBC by hand (and it looks like it) or using a buggy library. If you're doing JDBC by hand, can't you find all usages of `Connection` in your code and check that they release resources properly?